# What is the addressing problem of SLIP?

Tags: network, ppp

In the [RFC1055](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1055) that describes SLIP, in the DEFICIENCIES section, there is a bullet named "addressing" which says:

> both computers in a SLIP link need to know each other's IP
> addresses for routing purposes.  Also, when using SLIP for
> hosts to dial-up a router, the addressing scheme may be quite
> dynamic and the router may need to inform the dialing host of
> the host's IP address.  SLIP currently provides no mechanism
> for hosts to communicate addressing information over a SLIP
> connection.

I try to understand this. As far as I understand, SLIP is used in order to allow TCP/IP connections between two hosts over a serial line. It's a simple protocol that basically just marks where each IP packet ends, nothing more.

If so, there are only 2 ends to this connection. What kind of addressing should we expect when we only have 2 ends?

Can someone describe a common use case where this protocol is used, and what kind of "addressing" would help there?

Comment: Why are you so hung up on SLIP? Nothing has used SLIP for decades. The ISP I worked for 30 years ago, stopped supporting SLIP in 1998, and stopped selling it in 1995. PPP can negotiate params making it easy to support dynamic addressing. SLIP requires static addresses (which is "wasteful", even in 95) or a scripted login that can be told what your address should be. (dynamic IP with SLIP is messy.)

Comment: @Rickey, It wasn't written anywhere in this site that you need to specify _why_ you're interested in something. You can feel free to ignore my questions about SLIP. That being said - I have an old laptop without WiFi connectivity and I want to use an ESP8266 as a WiFi adapter, and I think SLIP is what I need. I just like to know as much possible about a technology when I'm using it. This is more for educational purposes

Comment: Remember that questions about historical trivia or not applicable to modern business networking are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: As Ron just said, you're treading on historical trivia, and there's every indication you aren't talking about a professionally managed business network. A laptop without wifi is going to be decades old. (the compaq lte5480, just happens to be on my workbench - don't ask - supports whatever I plug in the PCMCIA slot. The same is true of my sony viao FX?? - usb wifi adapter.)

Answer (score 2):

SLIP simply provided no means to negotiate connection parameters like addressing. (I'm using past tense because I cannot imagine that anyone is still using this laborious, even archaic protocol.)

So, routing and addressing information had to be exchanged outside of the protocol - basically, what address range(s) were used on each end. Since link partners need to know how to address each other, they had to pass the information in some other form: a setup instruction sheet, verbal discussion, or similar.

Comment: but why do they need to know each other's IP addresses? Host A knows that it can find Host B on the other side of the serial line. Why does it need to know Host B's IP address?

Comment: No. Host A doesn't know that it can find any other host on the other side. If you don't simply send everything over SLIP - there might be other interfaces - you need to know which addresses there are. You need to set up a route. If there's a remote DNS server that requires setup as well.

Comment: So the assumptions are : 1. We have 2 hosts connected with a serial line. 2. At least one of them (Host A) may have other interfaces - so it must know to which interface is should route an IP packet. And the problem is: we need to configure this Host A in some form about the IP of Host B. Correct so far? So is this opposed to what? having the protocol enable Host B to tell Host A his IP address?

Comment: This is opposed to today's common methods to configure a remote client *entirely* through the connecting protocol: client IP, client subnet, default route, additional routes, DNS servers, ... Last but not least, *authentication* is essential today which SLIP cannot provide. All this is covered by PPP which is still in extremely common use with PPPoE or PPPoA.

Comment: @Zac76, what do you mean by "Host A doesn't know that it can find any other host on the other side". SLIP is a communication protocol used by 2 entities to transfer IP packets over a serial line.. what am I missing?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that each host just uses a single SLIP interface and 'everything else' is on the other side. Just imagine a host with a local (Ethernet) network and two or three SLIP interfaces *on each side*. Then it becomes very obvious that quite a bit of setup and pre-setup communication become necessary.

Comment: @YoavKlein so how does a host on one side know the IP address of the hosts on the other side? It doesn't.

Comment: @Zac67, "a host connected to a local Ethernet network, and two or three SLIP interfaces of each side" - On each side of what exactly? please clarify.

Comment: On each side of each SLIP interface.